# How to add new device in uboot?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, u-boot

I want to access the different peripherals of i-MX6 at uboot level but I don't know how to do that?
How to add support for new devices in u-boot?
what are the differences between drivers present in u boot level and kernel level?

Comment: Are you talking about device tree blob, or about actual driver in U-Boot? For the latter you have to recompile U-Boot with driver enabled if it's already there, or write one and compile it otherwise.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be helping to raise your content quality

Answer (score 4):

The five (4) boot phases.

```
1.ROM loads x-load (MLO)
2.X-load loads u-boot -->  Primary boot-loader
3.U-boot reads commands/Load kernel --> Secondary Boot-Loader
4.Kernel reads root file system.
```

**x-loader (Primary Boot-Loader) :**
The x-loader configures the pin muxing, clocks, DDR, and serial console, so that it can access and load the second stage bootloader (u-boot) into the DDR

**U-Boot (Secondary Boot-Loader) :**
The u-boot can perform CPU dependent and board dependent initialization and configuration not done in the x-loader. The u-boot also includes fastboot functionality for partitioning and flashing the eMMC. The u-boot runs on the Master CPU (CPU ID 0), which is responsible for the initialization and booting; at the same time, the Slave CPU (CPU ID 1) is held in the “wait for event” state.

U-Boot is kind of firmware. It'll basically initialize basic functionality. Like Display, CPU0, FastBoot functionality, Create a temporary file system for loading a kernel and Loading Kernel.

**Kernel Driver :**
 A device driver is a program that controls a particular type of device that is attached to your computer. There are device drivers for printers, displays,Touch, CD-ROM readers, diskette drives, and so on.

U-Boot is mainly for loading a Operating System (Kernel). Device Driver is part of kernel for controlling a device. you want to accesses your device in u-boot loader then you will have to initialize all need hardware for your device like memory an all.